# What is the optical (and possibly physiological) explanation behind the additive mixing of separate colour dots as used in printing?

Tags: visible-light

Industrial printing is based on autotypical colour mixing, the simultaneous effect of subtractive and additive colour mixing. This makes it possible to render a large set of colours using only four standardized colours (CMYK):

[image: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/52/07/805207d14d35a102f6c2761c1842c7e0.jpg]

I do understand additive and subtractive colour mixing but I struggle to understand how two dots *next to each other*, i.e. with *no* overlapping, additively mix to another colour. This is illustrated in the lower part of the following diagram, e.g. a red dot and a green dot are perceived as a blue dot (provided they are small/far enough):

[image: https://www.xrite.com/-/media/modules/weblog/blog/additive-subtractive-color-models/appearanceofcolorpng.png?la=en&hash=94274F6479B458F97BCCCBF0F2580E7F7FCD6F76]

I guess the answer revolves around the size of the dots, the amplitude of the resulting light wave and some properties of the human eye but I could not find any detailed physical/mathematical relation between them so far.

Comment: Would the fact that our eyes have finite size, and so the light from two closely spaced dots closer than our eyes can resolve them as separate, would overlap and be detected as one merged dot, be sufficient to answer your question?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Using your words, I'd say that my question is: What can our eye "resolve", i.e. with a given dot size at a given space from one another, 1) at what distance from our eye do they have to be for us to perceive them as one? and if it is not the same answer: 2) at what distance do they have to be to appear smaller than the wavelength of the colour they reflect?

Comment: (2) will be totally different. The wavelength of colours is in the hundreds of nanometers range. You would have to put them so far away that you can never see them. As for (1), did you miss the huge hooha over retina displays a few years back? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display but of course, the real thing you want to look at, is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fovea_centralis#Angular_size_of_foveal_cones

Comment: I think I am getting closer now, thank you. Does that mean that we perceive two adjacent point as one, as soon as their corresponding angle of view fall below the angle of view of a single cone cell?

Comment: I suppose you can put it that way, but it is always better to be mathematically precise about these things. The important concept is the Rayleigh criterion for distinguishing two circular blobs through circular lens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution